# will_paginate undefined method error - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination

I just [installed the gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/will_paginate) for will_paginate and it says that it was installed successfully. I followed [all the instructions](http://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) listed with the plugin and I am getting an 'undefined method `paginate' for' error. Can't find much in the way of Google search and haven't been able to fix it myself (obviously). Here is the code:

PostsController

```
def index
    @tag_counts = Tag.count(:group => :tag_name, :order => 'updated_at DESC', :limit => 10)
    @posts = Post.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 50

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @posts }
      format.json { render :json => @posts }
      format.atom
    end
  end
```

/model/post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :body, :title
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tags, :dependent => :destroy

  cattr_reader :per_page
    @@per_page = 10

end
```

/posts/views/index.html.erb

```
  <%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

UPDATE
I used the script/console to determine if will_paginate was correctly installed properly and it wasn't. I had to add:

```
config.gem 'will_paginate', :version => '~> 2.3.11', :source => 'http://gemcutter.org'
```

to the /config/environments.rb file and restart the server. Works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the script/console to determine if will_paginate was correctly installed properly and it wasn't. I had to add:

```
config.gem 'will_paginate', :version => '~> 2.3.11', :source => 'http://gemcutter.
```

works great. Simple fix.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced an undefined method error with the will_paginate gem (using Rails 3) because I mistakenly placed the . . .

```
gem 'will_paginate'
```

. . . command in the wrong place in Gemfile. Make sure you have it placed where it will be available to all runtime environments--not nested inside a bundle for a partitioned-off environment such as:

```
group :test do
.
.
.
end
```